# Implement Interface with Generic Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I can't call string methods on `element` and `argument`.
The UML diagram tells me that `StartsWith` class has a Generic Type`T>String`. I read in an other post you need to implement it in this way `<T extends String>`.
I would like to substitute Object for T in the 
method here `public boolean predicate(Object element, Object argument)` but the compiler throws at me thats not possible.

interface:

```
public interface Intaf<T> {

    public boolean pres(T element, T argument);
}
```

class:

```
public class StartsWith <T extends String> implements Intaf {

    @Override
    public boolean pres(Object element, Object argument) {

        String firstLetterElement = element.substring(0,1);

        String firstLetterArgument = argument.substring(0,1);

        return firstLetterElement.equals(firstLetterArgument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
public class StartsWith <T extends String> implements Intaf<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean pres(T element, T argument) {

        String firstLetterElement = element.substring(0,1);

        String firstLetterArgument = argument.substring(0,1);

        return firstLetterElement.equals(firstLetterArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` is final. So `T` can only have the type of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement `Intaf<T>`.  Just saying `Intaf` implies `Intaf<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change as `Intaf<T>` and change the arguments as type T

```
@Override
public boolean pres(T element, T argument) {
 ....
}
```